# Delete last word using Command + Backspace

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is there a setting to delete the last word using the command key and backspace?

Currently this combination of keys deletes the current line. Instead, I want to delete the last word (before the cursor).

How can I do that *natively* (without any other apps, if possible)? Is there a terminal command to run or maybe an option somewhere?

In the terminal I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, but I'm interested how to do that in UI apps (browser, and other non-terminal applications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Option-Delete        Delete the word to the left of the insertion point.

Have a look at the Document shortcuts section in: [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Comment: Can you take a look at [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/237805/87092), too? Thanks!

Comment: @Ionică Bizău, I looked at your other question. I normally do not use that feature and having just now tested it, it is only working sporadically on my system running OS X 10.8.5. So there's not really any help I can offer, sorry.