# Tap and drag delay

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, trackpad, ui

I enabled dragging with the trackpad in my preferences:

> [image]

It works well, but there is a delay after I release my finger from the touchpad.

So, I:

1. Double tap and begin dragging
2. If I release my finger from touchpad and then put it again, quick enough, and move the mouse, it's dragging the window.

Instead of that I want to stop dragging the window when releasing the finger.

How to do that? Is there a setting or a terminal command to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"without drag lock" is the correct setting for this – however, the drag lock only turns off after a half-second of inactivity, to make sure that the drag is finished. So, you must wait just a bit before touching the trackpad again.

You can also tap once at the end of your drag to release the drag lock.

If you use the "three finger drag" setting, no delay is required to move the cursor with a single finger.

Comment: is there a way to decrease this 1/2 sec delay ?

Comment: this is so irritant.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı like many other things in macOS. Enough customization does not seem to be a priority for Apple.

Comment: @scarface I changed my OS from macOS to windows. Then everything is well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing "[BetterTouchTools](https://yuji.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/mac-osx-multitouch-spaces-custom-multitouch-windows-7-like-windows/)" which removes the delay completely along with allowing you to add your own gestures.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant

Comment: Please let us know how to do this in BTT. After googling and looking through BTT it is not obvious.

Comment: The option was removed as it isn't supported anymore for the newer versions of the macOs.

Comment: @nohillside, Your suggestion would indeed improve the answer greatly, but if the link goes down, it still be close to useless because the recommended tool will require searching to find (and it may not exist).