# On a MacBook, the trackpad does not immediately release after dragging and letting go of a window

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

System Preferences > Accessibility > Pointer Control > Trackpad Options > Enable dragging with trackpad. After enabling this setting, double-clicking allows you to drag windows, but after dragging, the window does not immediately release and remains in a sticky state for a short period. I have to wait a moment or click again to cancel the stickiness after dragging. Note that in the trackpad dragging options, I have already set it not to lock the mouse.

Comment: Isn't that how it's supposed to work? Otherwise you couldn't drag more than the width of the trackpad.

Comment: @Tetsujin if it's intentional then I understand OP's confusion/frustration, because you can move the cursor from one side of the screen to the other using less than half of the trackpad anyway

Comment: What I need is operational certainty and a sufficiently quick response. The only premise for this setting to be viable is if every drag action necessarily involves a super-long distance, but such a premise does not exist. Moreover, I have other quick and effective methods for moving windows over long distances. If the designers really think this feature could be useful, what they should do is set the default behavior to release immediately and then provide an option to enable delayed release. So, we should get back to the problem itself, instead of directly eliminating the issue.

Comment: I'm on an older OS here [Mojave] where this seems to be toggled by 'enable dragging (with or without) drag lock. 'With' demands another click to disengage, 'without' needs just a half second pause/dwell after you let go. Personally, I usually drag with force-click rather than double-click, & there is no dwell period on that.

Comment: In fact, to avoid this issue, I have already turned off the setting mentioned in the question. I am currently using the force press to drag windows operation, which has slightly improved my experience. However, I am still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: An hour trawling the interwebz finds that there are many people trying to find a fix for this… none successfully. Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/237805/85275